# HAproxy - Load Balancer working with frontend IP but not with hostname

Tags: iis, haproxy

We have Haproxy installed in a CentOS VM.
I need to load balance access to 3 IIS servers using SSL.
The VIP was created on keepalived.conf and the SSL certificate is being issued.

If I go to HAproxy stats page everything is green and I can see the traffic.
DNS was set up.
However, I am only being forwarded to the IIS page when using the ip address of the frontend load balancer.
If I try to use the hostname I am getting a 403 forbidden access error message in the browser.

[image: 403 forbidden error]

My Haproxy config file shows the following.

```
listen services
    bind 10.10.10.120:443 ssl crt /etc/haproxy/certs/wildcard.example.com.pem 
    mode http
    maxconn 2000
    balance leastconn
    option redispatch
    server iisl004 10.10.9.100:80 check
    server iisl005 10.10.9.101:80 check
```

I can I be forwarded using the hostname instead of the IP address?
Is the error coming from the IIS server?

If I type https://10.10.10.120 in the browser it is working fine.

Comment: To what IP address does "the hostname" resolve?

Comment: @GerardH.Pille It is resolving to the correct IP. From the load balancer perspective everything was ok. It was just that while using the IP it showed the IIS splash page, with hostname it was sending the 403 forbidden message. This was responsibility of the IIS developer. After he set all the forwarding rules the issue was fixed.